# "Composer update failed: "/usr/local/bin/composer" could not be written." after installing Composer using the terminal

Tags: 20.04, error-handling, execute-command, laravel, composer

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have installed Composer directly using the terminal, but I'm getting this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]                                    
  Filesystem exception:                                                        
  Composer update failed: "/usr/local/bin/composer" could not be written.      
  rename(/home/smiley/.cache/composer/composer-temp5193870.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied
```

I was searching on Google and Stack, but some suggestions I tried are not working.

Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to run a CLI-based PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily add the rights to your working user, then update composer w/o errors and then get back the rights.

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/
composer self-update
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Run composer update with admin privileges

```
sudo composer self-update
```

Comment: I have composer 2.1.9 installed `sudo composer self-update` = `sudo: composer: command not found`